# Repairing ArcGIS license that became untrusted after Windows 10 install?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license, arcgis-license-manager, windows-10

I've installed Windows 10 update. After that I get that message when I try to run ArcGis:

[image]

I have ArcGis 10.3 Education version.

Here screen from ArcGis Administrator:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Please include error messages as text rather than just pictures so that they are available to future searches.  I would be suspicious of that "untrusted" value in the Authorized column, and you are not showing us the Expiration Date value.

Comment: Exporation date value is novmber 2017 ;)

Comment: Here's a related [knowledge base article](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011382). I think Ithere was GeoNet discussions about it. When you upgrade the operating system, there's a change which makes it look like a new machine/installation and triggers the "untrusted" setting. Here's [another](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/162643). You may need to request another license or call Customer Service/Technical Support.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a license borrowed from a license server, rather than a standalone license, is to rename "C:\ProgramData\ESRI\FLEXnet" to "C:\ProgramData\ESRI**~FLEXnet**", and then run ArcGIS Administrator. You will then be able to borrow a new license from the license server.

Comment: Thank you very much, by renaming the FLEXnet and reauthorizing it, this methods works,

Answer (score 1):

Following the second link provided by @mkennedy's comment I found an [FAQ: Is Windows 10 certified with Esri's ArcGIS products?](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000013232) which says:

> **Licensing Issue**
>
> For those running ArcGIS 10.3.1 and upgrading to Windows 10, when
>   launching ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS Administrator, or ArcGIS License
>   Manager, the following error message may be received:
>
> "The ArcGIS Server Administrator has detected that your license have
>   become untrusted. This can occur when a machine hardware configuration
>   has changed or licenses have been restored from a backup. Please click
>   the 'Repair' button below to repair your untrusted licenses."

That FAQ includes a procedure for repairing the license.

Answer (score -2):

Remove folder c:\programdata\esri and solved.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.